# OOP: passing settings to Builder class

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

In my client I would like to specify strategies to be used in the class produced by builder.

However, I can't pass these strategy objects to builder, because their initialization is partially handled by builder. Yet, I still have to communicate builder which object to use and which additional parameters to pass it.

Here's Builder class

```
public class MarketGeneratorBuilder {
    private MarketGenerator.Parameters parameters;

    public MarketGeneratorBuilder(MarketGenerator.Parameters parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    public MarketGenerator build() {
        return new MarketGenerator(
            parameters,
            new GoodsGenerator(
                new UniformDistribution(
                    new ValueRange(0,parameters.getNumberOfLevels()-1)
                )
            ),
            new ITGenerator(),
            new OTGenerator(),
            new IOTGenerator(
                new UniformDistribution(
                    new ValueRange(1,parameters.getNumberOfLevels()-2)
                ),
                new BundlesGenerator(
                    new ForwardMarkovDistribution(
                        new MarkovDistribution.Parameters(
                            new ValueRange(0,parameters.getNumberOfLevels()-1),
                            0.1,
                            0.1
                        )
                    ),
                    new UniformDistribution(
                        new ValueRange(1,parameters.getNumberOfGoodsToCreate()-1)
                    )
                ),
                new BundlesGenerator(
                    new BackwardMarkovDistribution(
                        new MarkovDistribution.Parameters(
                            new ValueRange(0,parameters.getNumberOfLevels()-1),
                             0.2,
                             0.2
                        )
                    ),
                    new UniformDistribution(
                        new ValueRange(1,parameters.getNumberOfGoodsToCreate()-1)
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Distributions (UniformDistribution, ForwardMarkovDistribution, ForwardMarkovDistribution and potentially more to come) are hardcoded now, but should be chosen by client. The value range is defined by Builder (the ValueRange objects). Yet, some distributions take additional parameters (ForwardMarkovDistribution takes ValueRange, alpha, beta), which should be defined by client.

The only solution I can see is to pull ValueRange from constructor into setter.  But it seems wrong as its an essencial field for the object. Also, I would like client code to not contain internal logic of the builder. More like,

```
DistributionType levelDistribution = new DistributionType(Distributions.UNIFORM);
DistributionType goodsDistribution = new DistributionsType(Distributions.MARKOV_FORWARD, 0.1,0.1);
```

But in this case I dont understand how to enforce data integrity. Meaning that when the client chooses Distributions.UNIFORM there are no more parameters to pass. Or in case of Distributions.MARKOV_FORWARD he has to pass alpha and beta.

So, I was hoping you could point me to a better pattern. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For full flexibility, add a provider/factory for each of the distributions:

```
interface DistributionProvider<D extends Distribution> {
  D create(ValueRange vr);
}

class UniformDistributionProvider implements DistributionProvider<UniformDistribution> {
  UniformDistribution create(ValueRange vr) {
    return new UniformDistribution(vr);
  }
}

class ForwardMarkovDistributionProvider implements DistributionProvider<ForwardMarkovDistribution> {

  private final MarkovDistribution.Parameters params;

  ForwardMarkovDistributionProvider(MarkovDistribution.Parameters pParams) {
    params = pParams;
  }

  ForwardMarkovDistribution create(ValueRange vr) {
    return new ForwardMarkovDistribution(vr, params);
  }
}

// etc.
```

(Remove the `ValueRange` from  `MarkovDistribution.Parameters`.)

Basically, each of the providers stores all necessary parameters for the distribution, except the `ValueRange`.
Then clients can instantiate the provider for the distribution they want, configuring it with the appropriate values.
The builder would get those instances of `DistributionProvider` and use these to create the distributions, passing a `ValueRange`.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of different patterns here.

- You could have a couple of different `build` methods.  `buildUniform()` and `buildMarkov(float alpha, float beta)`.
- You could have a couple of different builder classes: `MarketGeneratorMarkovBuilder`.  They could have a base class with a protected `build` method.  [Not sure I like this one]
- You could add the `alpha` and `beta` values to the `parameters` class and throw an exception if they aren't available for the `MARKOV_FORWARD` and throw exception if they *are* available for `UNIFORM`.
- If the `ValueRange` is constant for the entire builder then I see no reason why, as you mention, you couldn't add it to the `parameters` or put a setter on the builder to inject it.
- You might consider using dependency injection (in Spring fashion) for all of the constant sub classes.  The builder could have setters for all of them instead of being hard coded.

Hope this helps.